# How do we create an AttributeSet in Android without xml

Tags: java, kotlin, attributes, android-layoutparams

I know we can set AttributeSet without creating custom attributes in xml

```
XmlPullParser parser = resources.getXml(myResource);
AttributeSet attributes = Xml.asAttributeSet(parser);
```

I want do do something like this

> kotlin

```
val attrs: AttributeSet = AnArray("android:orientation=Horizontal","
   android:layout_height=match_parent")
```

> java

```
AttributeSet attrs = new AnArray("android:orientation=Horizontal","
   android:layout_height=match_parent")
```

Is it possible to type an Array and store it as Attribute set?

Comment: Android doesn't expose any simple way to do this. AttributeSet is an interface with many methods. There's no publicly exposed implementation class you can use.

Comment: Oh ok I see.. I will have to resource to creating an xml with default attributes